# How to locally allocate array-pointer in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, local

Think of a pointer-datatype, for instance to a floating-pointer number.

```
typedef float* flPtrt;
```

How would I allocate an array of 3 elements in the local scope? I guess using `malloc` and `free` withing the same scope produces overhead, but what's the alternative?

```
void foo() {
    flPtrt ptr = malloc(sizeof(float)*3);
    // ...
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: That is the correct way to do it.  What sort of alternative do you want?

Comment: The only alternative I see would be to actually use an array, but that seems to fall outside the scope of your request.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde:  Agreed.  Having `foo()` declare `float arr[3]` is so obvious, I didn't think OP could not know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your'e looking for is the `alloca()` function.
I'm not sure it's standard C, but it exists in GNU, and it worked on my visual studio.
So this is how you use it:

```
int n = 5;
int* a = (int*) alloca(sizeof(int) * n);
```

It creates an array of elements on the stack (rather than on the heap with malloc).
Advantages: less overhead, no need to free manually (when you return from your method, the stack folds back and the memory is lost)
Disadvantage: If you want to return a pointer from a method NEVER use alloca, since you will be pointing at something that no longer exists after exiting the function. One can also argue that the stack is usually smaller than the heap, so if you want larger space use malloc.
See more [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_3.html#SEC45)

Comment: Note that Microsoft does not support C99, so you can't use `int a[n];` like Mysticial has suggested, although IMHO it is a good alternative on other platforms

Comment: That's what I searched for. However, I think I will stick to `malloc()` and `free()` or to `float arr[3]; flPtr ptr = arr` due to deprecation and warnings I've read about `alloca()`.

Answer (score 2):

If `3` is known at compile time and is small enough, you can declare a local array and use it as a pointer

```
void foo() {
    float array[3];
    flPtrt ptr = array;
}
```

If the size is bigger or variable, you have to use dynamic memory as in your example.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but I think the whole point of the question is the type that `typedef` aliases can be changed and you want to only fix the `typedef` not the rest of the program.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the required size of the array ahead of time, you could just allocate it as a stack variable and avoid heap memory management.

Otherwise, the approach you outlined is appropriate and there is not really an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array.

```
void foo(void) // note that "void foo()" is obsolete
{
    float data[3];
    float *ptr = data;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That `free(ptr)` will be problematic

Comment: is `void foo()` not supported by every compiler, or what is the reason for using `void foo(void)` instead?
That's actually what I searched for, but I wondered if there was something else. Unfortunately, this is more unnatural syntax, and using `malloc()` and `free()` does always give me a feeling of that is an overhead for allocating memory on the heap and freeing it again.